# Why connected props are not populated correctly in mapToDispatch ownProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I really can't wrap my head around scoping of mapStateToProps and ownProps in mapDispatchToProps

```
const MyComponent = (props) => (
    <button onClick={props.onClick}>{props.myProp} / {props.otherProp}</button>
)

const ConnctedMyComponent = connect(
    (state) => ({
        myProp: 'mapped',
        otherProp: 'other'

    }),
    (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
        onClick: () => {
            console.log(ownProps);
        }
    })
)(MyComponent)
```

Log shows

```
{ myProp: 'original' }
```

1. Why `myProp` is not set to `mapped`?
2. Why `otherProp` is not available?
3. Button content is properly set to `mapped / other`
4. Is this the way I should pass mapped prop to mapped dispatch prop?

```
const MyComponent = (props) => (
    <button onClick={() => props.onClick(props.myProp)}>{props.myProp} / {props.otherProp}</button>
)
```

5. Is there a way to bind mapped dispatch callback to connected component (as in accessing mapped store properties)?

Thanks

Comment: Could be the error in the reducers? can you show the reducer?

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/issues/250, this is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: @DanielArtola No reducers used here so its just mapping 'issue'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ownProps` is only the props that are passed to the outer wrapper component generated by connect.

I suppose you've created your component like that:

```
<ConnctedMyComponent myProp="original" />
```

The `ownProps` in this case will always be `{myProp: "original"}` because it reflects the props given to the outer wrapper.

As you suggested, if you want access to your connected props you will have to pass them as parameter:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => (
  <button onClick={() => props.onClick(props.myProp)}>{props.myProp} / {props.otherProp}</button>
);
```

And retrieving them inside the `onClick` dispatch method:

```
onClick: (props) => {
  console.log(props);
}
```

Comment: Ok. Makes sense, however I've got feeling that it would be convenient to have way of accessing wrapped components props inside dispatcher mapper. Thanks.

Comment: For the moment there is no alternatives. If it answer your question please validate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`ownProps` are the props that are passed to the **wrapper** component ,`ConnctedMyComponent` in your example, when you render it ( eg. `<ConnctedMyComponent myProp='mapped'/>`)

> 1) Why myProp is not set to mapped?

Because you didn't passe it as a prop to `ConnctedMyComponent`, and so it's not present in `ownProps`

> 2) Why otherProp is not available?

Same as 1, you didn't passe it as a prop to `ConnctedMyComponent`, and so it's not present in `ownProps`

> 3) Button content is properly set to mapped / other

Whatever you set in `mapStateToProps` is passed down to the **wrapped** component `MyComponent`

> 4) Is this the way I should pass mapped prop to mapped dispatch prop?

yes

Comment: Sorry. Didnt paste <ConnctedMyComponent myProp="original" /> in question. So I've used myProp but it won't update anyways due to nature of wrapping and scope.